# Debugging multiple Google form submissions on single click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, google-forms

I'm trying to do a kind of purchase request app built off of a Google Spreadsheet. For awhile, (like the whole time I've been working on this), my code was working. For each line in the order sheet, it would loop through the values, fill in the Google form inputs, submit the form, then start the process again.

Yesterday I noticed it was <strike>submitting each line twice</strike> submitting the first line once, second line twice, third line three times, and so on. Then it stopped submitting at all. Then it started again submitting multiple times, then stopped. Could you guys please take a look at my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
function formSubmit() {

  //Create unique ID (number of milliseconds since 1/1/70)
  var d = new Date();
  var n = d.getTime();
  var uniqueID = n.toString();

  //Loop through the lines of the order, fill in the values, submit
  $('.orderline').each(function(i, obj) {

    //Stop the default redirect so we can submit multiple times
    $('#ss-form').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        url: "https://docs.google.com/a/vt.edu/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSf77MuDLeqyPbuDCBcpVagi6-hdiUpgZtr0CbuJ3kO-vXPswg/formResponse",
          data: $(this).serialize(),
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "jsonp",
          success: function(data) {
                console.log("Submission successful");
          },
          error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.log("Submission failed: "  + error);
          },
        });
      });

    $("#entry_1725077600").val(uniqueID);

    var name = $("#personname").val();
    var email = $("#personemail").val();

    $("#entry_1352722479").val(name);
    $("#entry_1024015951").val(email);

    //etc.

    $("#ss-form").submit();

  });
```

The form is public if you guys want to take a look. Note I have two forms submitting at once on the same click; the one above is for the items in the order, the second one is for metadata about the order.

EDIT: formSubmit() is being called from a second function that uploads files to Google Drive (if there's a better way to do this please do let me know):

```
if(document.getElementById('fUpload').value!='') {

        var user = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get();
        var oauthToken = user.getAuthResponse().access_token;

        var uploadObj = $("[id$=fUpload]");
        var file = uploadObj.prop("files")[0];
        var metadata = {
            'title': file.name,
            'description': " ",
            'mimeType': file.type || 'application/octet-stream',
            "parents": [{
                "kind": "drive#file",
                "id": "0B5zM5ktmwJ2fN0c3RWYxWC1rUzQ"
            }]
        };
        var arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array(file);
        var uploadData = new Blob(arrayBufferView, {type: file.type || 'application/octet-stream'});

        try{
            var uploader =new MediaUploader({
                file: file,
                token: oauthToken,
                metadata: metadata,
                params: {
                    convert:false,
                    ocr: false
                }
            });
            uploader.upload();
        } catch(exc){
            showErrorMessage("Error: " + exc);
            $("#fUpload").val(" ");
        }
    } else {
        formSubmit();
    }
});
```

And then for successful responses:

```
MediaUploader.prototype.onContentUploadSuccess_ = function (e) {
    if (e.target.status == 200 || e.target.status == 201) {

        var response = e.target.response; //Get the response body
        var parsed = JSON.parse(response); //Parse the response body to JS object
        var fileID = parsed.id; //Get the file ID from the response
        var linkToFile = "https://drive.google.com/open?id=" + fileID;

        $("#entry_1703377267").val(linkToFile); //Add the file ID as the value of the file ID input field
        formSubmit(); //Run the rest of the form submit functions

        this.onComplete(e.target.response);

    } else if (e.target.status == 308) {
        this.extractRange_(e.target);
        this.retryHandler.reset();
        this.sendFile_();
    }
};
```

EDIT 2: I never see success or error messages in the console. Also, it looks like things aren't being submitted twice, they're being submitted in a pattern: first item once, second item twice, third item three times, etc.

Comment: How is `formSubmit` called? is it possible it is getting called multiple times?

Comment: It's called from a second function that uploads media to Google Drive, but it only allows one file to be uploaded at a time; I'll put it in the edit.

Comment: I would not use an AJAX request to submit directly to the Google Form.  You can still use an AJAX request, but make a POST request to an Apps Script Web App.  Then have the Web App submit the request to the Google Form with `FormApp`  So, create a stand alone Apps Script Web App.  Then publish it as a Web App.  Get the published URL of the Web App, and make the AJAX request to that web app URL with a payload of the answers and question ID's.  That process will be much better for controlling what happens.  If the starting point is a Google Spreadsheet, then you don't need AJAX or client side

Comment: code for any of this.  There is no need to fill in the Form.  You can make a new Form submission in Apps Script server side code.

Comment: @SandyGood, do you know if there's a good tutorial for this? I've made Web Apps before that write data to a sheet, but I can't figure out how to send data from another website except through the URL. I don't think I'd want to send all the form data that way?

Comment: You need a Web App with either a `doPost(e)` or `doGet(e)` function.  Both of those function names are reserved function names.  They look for an event and then if the event happens, run the function.  `doPost(e)` looks for an HTTPS POST request made to the published URL of the Web App.  You get the data from the "event object" which in the examples above are designated by the letter `e`  "e" for "event"  You need to create a new response and then submit it:  [Link to documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#createResponse())